# Manual configuration of global exception handler in spring webflux through httpHandler bean

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I am developing a set of reusable stuff like filters, global exception handlers and other spring webflux components, that would be used by reactive spring apps (webflux)

Since, this is a library (a jar), that will be consumed by apps, I dont want to annotate the global exception handler class with @Configuration and instead would like to let the applications programmatically configure the exception handler as needed. I see from the docs, that the way to configure the WebExceptionHandler is through the HttpHandler.

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestApplicationConfig {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    public HttpHandler routeHandler() {
        return WebHttpHandlerBuilder.applicationContext(applicationContext)
                .exceptionHandler(new ServiceExceptionHandler())
                .build();
    }
}

//exception handler
@NoArgsConstructor
@Order(-2)
@Slf4j
public class ServiceExceptionHandler implements ErrorWebExceptionHandler {

    @SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems")
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, Throwable err) {
    }
}
```

The routeHandler bean gets called by the framework, but the exception handler is not called for any exception. If I have @Configuration in the exception handler class, then it is getting called. Wondering if I making a mistake in the way I am exposing the HttpHandler as a bean

Comment: I realised that the routeHandler bean is initialized and sets up the WebFilters correctly even if I remove @Component annotations from the filter classes. So manual configuration of filters via HttpHandler seems to work fine. This may be a bug in webflux

Comment: You say you dont want to use `@Component` because this is a library? Libraries in spring are called ”starters” and you are already using spring specific classes so your library wont work with anything else then spring so i dont see any reason not to use spring specific annotations. If you wish to write a library, write a starter.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf set of such libraries have a common base package and spring boot applications consuming these libraries scan the base package for spring components. I dont want to force the components part of this library on the applications, it should be rather manually configured and included. That is my requirement.

Comment: That is why you use a starter and select what should be loaded under what circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ThomasAndolf , I shall try this out

Comment: here is the official documentation for creating your own starter https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-starter